# Parsing two files to pool data and create new Fasta file

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I have two files, *human.fa* and *protein-coding_gene.txt* (has hundreds of different protein info). I have to parse through protein-coding gene and then parse through human.fa (10 protein names) to pool the into a new fasta file.

protein-coding_gene.txt:

```
Protein1 PreviousNames1 PreviousSymbols1 Symbol1 Chromosome1
Protein2 PreviousNames2 PreviousSymbols2 Symbol2 Chromosome2
```

human.fa:

```
>Protein1  Sequence1
>Protein2 Sequence2
```

I need a new fasta file to output:

```
>Protein1 Synonyms1 Chromsome1 Sequence1
>Protein2 Synonyms2 Chromosome2 Sequence2
```

My current code is:

```py
class Protein:
    
    def __init__(self, Name, Synonyms, Chromosome):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Synonyms = Synonyms
        self.Chromosome = Chromosome
             
Proteins = []
with open('protein-coding_gene.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        parseline = line.rstrip().split("\t")
        Name = parseline[2]
        Synonyms = parseline[6]
        Chromosome = parseline[7]
        Proteins.append(Protein(Name, Synonyms, Chromosome))


f = open("human.fa")

seqs = {}
for i in f:
    line = i.strip()
    if line[0] == '>':
        l = line.split()
        gene = l[0][1:]
        seqs[gene] = ''
    else:
        seqs[gene] = seqs[gene] + line

        
f.close()

        
for p in Proteins:
    print(p.Name, p.Synonyms, p.Chromosome, sep=",")

for name, seq in seqs.items():
        print (name, seq)
        

from Bio import SeqIO
        
newhuman = []
SeqIO.write[newhuman, "fastaML.fa", "fasta")
```

Right now it prints everything from the protein-coding file that I want (Name, Synonyms, Chromosome) and the prints the entire human.fa file. I need it to sort through and only print the 10 protein names of the fasta file with the info from protein-coding_gene.txt and the sequence. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**The format you want is not a valid fasta format**. But if you still want the same output in `fastaML.fa` then you should not use SeqIO.write() method. Rather you should use basic file handling.

```py
class Protein:
    
    def __init__(self, Name, Synonyms, Chromosome):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Synonyms = Synonyms
        self.Chromosome = Chromosome

    def add_sequence(self, Sequence):
        self.Sequence = Sequence
             
Proteins = []
with open('protein-coding_gene.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        parseline = line.rstrip().split(" ")
        Name = parseline[0]
        Synonyms = parseline[1:4]
        Chromosome = parseline[4]
        Proteins.append(Protein(">"+Name, Synonyms, Chromosome))


f = open("human.fa")

seqs = {}
gene = ""
for i in f:
    line = i.strip()
    if line[0] == '>':
        l = line.split()
        gene = l[0]
        seqs[gene] = l[1]
    else:
        seqs[gene] = seqs[gene] + line

        
f.close()

for p in Proteins:
    for name, seq in seqs.items():
        if(p.Name == name):
            p.add_sequence(seq)     

with open('fastaML.fa', 'w') as file:
    for p in Proteins:
        file.write(p.Name + " " + p.Synonyms[0] + " " + p.Synonyms[1] + " " + p.Synonyms[2] + " " + p.Chromosome + " " + p.Sequence + "\n")
        #I have used single space here. You can modify it as per your need.
```

[Here is a working repl for your reference](https://repl.it/@pagalprogrammer/OffensiveCarelessFacts#main.py).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got an AttributeError if you can help me see where it is.

Comment: I checked your suggestion but I have to reject those changes as this is a general answer which gives an idea to the reader and might help someone even in the future. By looking at your code, I can tell that AttributeError is due to ```seqs[gene] = ''``` as you are leaving it blank. Rather, you should do ```seqs[gene] = l[1]```

Comment: But then you will have another error in the ```file.write()``` as it doesn't accept multiple parameters. So that's why I have used concatenation operation in it.